# Play Framework how to set selected option in the form?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I need to set `selected` option for `select` element, rendered with Play Framework helper. I could not find an example how to do it, even after looking [at the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.select$).

I tried to do it like this, but still default value is selected:

```
@select(
    field = form("selectedCategory"),
    options = categoriesSeq,
    '_default -> "Choose One",
    '_label -> "Select category",
    'selected -> "1"
)
```

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at [how use play forms](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms).

In your code, what is the variable `form`?

It should be a `play.api.data.Form` instance, passed into your view, from your controller.

I hope this helps.

Rhys

Comment: Actually I already use Play form. And this select is inside that form. But I can't figure out how to preselect some value with select helper

Comment: @Rhys is right, you don't select it "manually" in the template, you should do something like: `myForm.fill(myFormDataWithDefaultValues)`. Helpers are used just to render/show the data passed to them... There is also an interesting [library for rendering Bootstrap](http://adrianhurt.github.io/play-bootstrap/), have a look at it.

Comment: @insan-e Thanks, you have solved my problem. Can you make your comment an answer?

Comment: @user2975535 No need, you can mark this one as correct. ;) Glad I helped.